# Creating an Ubuntu partition on a MacBookPro 9,1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mac, macbook-pro

I have a MacBookPro 9,1 and I'd like to create a bootable Ubuntu partition (virtual machines are too hardware-limited); however, the [Mactel Support Matrix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages#Mactel%20Wiki%20Support%20Matrix) doesn't list anything for my model. Which of the following scenarios fits me the best?

1. It is not possible for my model
2. There is no specific guidance for my model (I can follow the general instructions for any model)
3. No guide has been written for my model (I'm on my own)
4. Other (please elaborate)

Comment: If/before you respond to this comment, please also consider alternatively editing your question and adding more detail to it. It might help others give you a better answer. An alternative to a dual boot is to use a virtualization product such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). If you try this, you might find it to be surprisingly acceptable. Another approach would be using suggestions for the `MacBookPro9,2`. For your purposes, the two models may not differ in a significant way.